# How to implement ServiceDiscovery Mechanism in node js

Tags: node.js, npm, microservices

I have three Microservices say **Sender**,**Receiver** and **Api-Gateway** in Node JS .What I am trying to implement is:

- Sender,Receiver and Api-Gateway will register on Discovery Clint.
- Sender Microservice will request Discovery client for Receiver and Api-gateway.
- Sender will call the receiver microservice using Api-gateway
- Let say if new microservice comes into the picture **NewReceiver** sender will call these NewReceiver using the same port 8765 (i.e using api-gateway)

When I try to implement I am getting following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTTg5.png)

But My service get register 
[Registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccBKB.png)
Thanks in advance:

Comment: Try https://github.com/coreos/etcd Blog: http://lukebond.ghost.io/service-discovery-with-etcd-and-node-js/

Comment: @RatanKumar : I am working on windows 7. I am getting `All servers returned error`